# Необходимо провести посчитать вес слова в тексте

Tags: текст, работа-с-текстом

Необходимо провести посчитать вес слова в тексте. Для этого нужно найти вес слова в тексте и сравнить его с весом слова в большом объеме текста. ВОт где взять этот большой набор текста на околоигровую тематику, я не представляю. Возможно по API или что-то такое...

Answer (score 0):

Библиотека NLTK для python и корпус русского языка решили проблему

Comment: старайтесь более развёрнуты ответы писать (просто что вам кажется очевидным явно выпишите, с самым простым примером кода)